# проблема применения нормали тайлмапа в unity

Tags: unity3d, opengl, шейдеры, light

[image: сразу иллюстрирую проблему]

Итак, суть вопроса - юнити рендерит нормали в тайлмапе не для всего тайлмапа, а для каждого тайла отдельно (ниже фото иллюстрирующее форму локации), что можно предпринять, чтобы нормаль приминялась к тайлмапу в целом, а не к каждому тайлу?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `TileMap` в принципе состоит из тайлов и никаким "целым" оно не является. `рендерит нормали`... боюсь ты не знаешь что такое нормали... нормали поверхностей рендарятся разве что для [gBuffer](https://www.3dgep.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/G-Buffer-900x506.jpg), что бы шейдеры могли их использовать.

Comment: Если тут имеется ввиду normal mapping, то для его отрисовки для кусков уровня из нескольких тайлов то либо у кажлого треугольника должна быть отдельная координата текстуры с нормалями, либо сначала рисовать кусок уровня в текстуру, а только потом накладывать нормали.